# Relation between the eigenvalues of a matrix A and the eigenvalues of its hermitian and skew-hermitian parts

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is well know that every matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ can be decomposed in a unique way as a sum of its hermitian part $H$ and its skew-hermitian part $K$:  $$A=\frac{A+A^*}{2}+\frac{A-A^*}{2}$$

However, there is a relationship between the eigenvalues of $A$, $H$ and $K$ that I´m trying to prove without success:

If the spectrums of $A, H, K$ are $\sigma(A)= \{ \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n  \}$, $\sigma(H)= \{ \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n \}$, $\sigma(K)= \{ \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n  \},$ then $$\sum_{i=1}^n\mathopen|\lambda_i\mathclose|^2\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n\mathopen|\alpha_i\mathclose|^2+ \sum_{i=1}^n\mathopen|\beta_i\mathclose|^2$$ With equality $\text{iff}$ $A$ is normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** My convention for $H$ and $K$ is to take $H = \frac{A + A^*}{2}$ and $K = \frac{A - A^*}{2i}$, so that $A = H + iK$.  With this convention, $H$ and $K$ are both Hermitian.  Notably, they have real eigenvalues.

First, note that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\sum |\lambda_i|^2 \leq \tr(A^*A)
$$
Something along these lines is usually proven together with the spectral theorem for normal matrices following Schur's theorem (see for example Horn and Johnson). Notably, the inequality becomes equality **if and only if $A$ is normal**.

Now, expand $\tr(A^*A)$ in terms of $H$ and $K$ to get
$$
\tr(A^*A) = 
\tr[(H+iK)^*(H+iK)]=
\tr(H^*H)+ i\tr(HK) - i \tr(HK)+\tr(K^*K)=\\
\tr(H^*H)+ \tr(K^*K)
$$
Note, however, that both $H$ and $K$ are normal.

Or, a yet more straightforward observation at this point is that since both $H$ and $K$ are *Hermitian*, we have
$$
\tr(H^*H)+ \tr(K^*K) = 
\tr(H^2)+ \tr(K^2) = \sum_{i} \alpha_i^2 + \sum_i \beta_i^2
$$
where we note that these eigenvalues must be *real*.

Comment: Is the first inequality troublesome?  Let me know.  Also, if you have not learned about the [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) of a matrix, then this proof might not be what was intended.

Comment: I knew about the Schur inequality and the Spectral Theorem. Thanks a lot!