# Eigenvalues for symmetric and skew-symmetric part of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

Every real matrix $A$ can be decomposed into symmetric and skew-symmetric part. Symmetric matrix has only real numbers as its eigenvalues (including $0$) and skew-symmetric matrix has only imaginary values (also including $0$).

- Could we infer from separate calculations of eigenvalues for
  symmetric and skew-symmetric about eigenvalues for matrix $A$ ?
- If so then can the same be said about eigenvectors calculated separately for these two parts of matrix and their relevance for eigenvectors of the whole matrix $A$?

**Edit (after 1 day)**

*If the answer for the questions above is too difficult to obtain in a general case maybe it would be possible to answer for a particular case:*

- why in the case of orthogonal matrices $R$ we can write down:
  $EGV(sym(R))+EGV(sk(R))= EGV(R)$ where $EGV$ is here a vector obtained from
  respectively ordered **values of eigenvalues** for symmetric part of $R$,
  skew-sym. part of $R$ and full matrix $R$.

*Example:

for 3-D rotation matrix we have ( it's hard to believe that it is just a coincidence)*

$EGV(sym(R)) =\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)\\
\cos(\theta)\\
 1
\end{bmatrix}  ,
 EGV(sk(R)) \begin{bmatrix}
i\sin(\theta)\\
-i\sin(\theta)\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
 EGV(R)=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\\
\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)\\
 1
\end{bmatrix}$

*Of course it would be better if it were proved starting from general properties of orthogonal matrix without calculating exact values of eigenvalues as I showed in the example above.*

Comment: I am afraid that there are no relations between the eigenvalues for symm and skewsymm and eigenvalues for $A$

Comment: More generally, knowing the eigenvalues of matrices $A$ and $B$ does not provide information on the eigenvalues of $aA+bB$.

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti Indeed, not much can be said, but some loose relations do exist, e.g. the trace of $A$ must be the sum of traces of the two decomposed parts.

Comment: @JeanMarie if $A$,$B$ are  any matrices maybe not, but distinction for symmetric and skew-symmetric gives nothing ?

Comment: @user1551 So  maybe the trace is the most important factor for this  connection ?

Comment: You are right, it may happen that we have particular properties for this decomposition. Sometimes something can be said about singular values instead of eigenvalues (in this respect, for example, I am almost certain that the symmetrical part of a matrix $A$ is the closest symmetrical matrix to $A$ in the sense of Frobenius norm).

Comment: have a look at (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1941701)

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, it seems quite interesting.. maybe nothing more can't be said in general case..

Comment: From your hypothesis we can deduce that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti So $A$ would be in this case non-invertible..

Comment: Yes @Widawensen

Comment: @AlessandroBlasetti So when sym. and sk.-sym. are both non-invertible their sum is also non-invertible. The proof would be difficult or easy ?

Comment: Thinking further, we also need $S:= \ker (A+A^T)\cap\ker (A-A^T)\neq \emptyset$, where $A+A^T$ is the symm part of $A$ and $A-A^T$ is the skew-symm. part of $A$. If so, we can take $x\in S$ such that $Ax=\frac {A-A^T}2 x+\frac{A+A^T}2 x=0$

Comment: We can produce some *inequalities* on the eigenvalues of $A$ based on those of the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts.  However, knowing the actual eigenvalues of $A$ is not possible.  One relevant result is given in Bhatia's matrix analysis

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Only inequalities.. its' a pity ... but for orthogonal matrices we have however equality .. why ?  Thank you Om. for edit :)

Comment: Orthogonal matrices are normal.  A (real) matrix will be normal if and only if its symmetric and skew-symmetric parts commute.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom And from that we have property EGV(sym(R))+EGV(sk(R))=EGV(R) mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Widawensen precisely.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If it so could you Om. put that into an answer with maybe a litlle more bits of explanation...

Answer (score 1):

I try to give a partial answer.
As @JeanMarie said in the comments there is no relationship between the eigenvalues of two matrices, $A$ and $B$, and some linear combination $aA+bB$.

Since $0$ is an eigenvalue of both the symmetric part of $A$ and the anty-symmetric part, if $\ker(A+A^T)\cap\ker(A-A^T)\neq\emptyset$, we can easily prove that that also $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it is a very limited conclusion but gives however some information about one eigenvalue for A.  Conclusions for more number of eigenvalues can be sometimes obtained   from sym, and sk-sym, part of a matrix A when we have some additional information about the matrix as it is - for example - in the case of 2-d and 3-d orthogonal matrices where sym. and sk-sym. parts give clues for eigenvalues.