# Prove the matrix is symmetric negative definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, lyapunov-functions

Given a curve of symmetric positive definite matrices $t\mapsto P(t)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a constant symmetric negative definite matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, how would you prove that the symmetric matrix $Q(t)=AP(t)+P(t)A$ is negative definite? Or, if it is not true, what property would you impose on $A$ so that this is true?

It is quite easy to prove that both $AP(t)$ and $P(t)A$ have negative eigenvalues, however, the sum of the two matrices I think needs additional assumptions on $A$ in order to have negative eigenvalues. I say this because for a given matrix $S$ with all negative eigenvalues, we can not say anything about the [Eigenvalues of symmetric and antisimmetric part](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004849/eigenvalues-for-symmetric-and-skew-symmetric-part-of-a-matrix#:%7E:text=Eigenvalues%20for%20symmetric%20and%20skew%2Dsymmetric%20part%20of%20a%20matrix,-linear%2Dalgebra%20matrices&text=Every%20real%20matrix%20A%20can,values%20(also%20including%200).)

It is clear that for some choice of $A$ it works, for example $A=-c^2Id$ but in general it does not hold for any $A$ negative definite.

An example where this does not work is $$A = \begin{bmatrix} -34 & 8 \\ 8 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$P=\begin{bmatrix} 26 & -4 \\ -4 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ where the matrix $AP+PA$ has a one eigenvalue which is positive and one which is negative. I know this is not a nice example, but I've found it playing a little bit with some matrices.

Do you understand what could be an additional property to impose onto $A$ to guarantee that $AP+PA$ has negative eigenvalues?

Answer (score -1):

Hints:

All the matrices here are real symmetric:

1. Any symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, so we can assume its form is
   $$\;\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\ldots&0\\
   0&\lambda_2&\ldots&0\\
   \ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
   0&0&\ldots&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}\;$$
2. Any symmetric matrix is positive definite (=PD) iff all its eigenvalues are positive, and it is negative definite (=ND) iff all its eigenvalues are negative.
3. The product of a PD matrix and a ND definite matrix is a ND matrix
4. The sum of two PD (ND) matrices is a PD (ND) matrix.

Now put the above together.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, these were my computations too, I just was concerned about assuming that they are diagonal matrices, but this is just a matter of checking it via diagonalization. Thank you again

Comment: Thinking a bit more about your answer, it is not clear to me how you can pass from 3 to 4, since the single matrices are not indeed negative definite, but they just have negative eigenvalues and are not symmetric in general. The symmetric part of a negative definite matrix I think is not negative definite for free... @DonAntonio please see the edit in the question

Comment: @Dadeslam There is no meaning, at least known to me, of "positive/negative definite" for general matrices, only for symmetric ones...and that's what I wrote at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Perfect, so you are assuming that $AP$ commute? Otherwise, how can $AP$ be symmetric and hence negative definite as you are saying?

Comment: @Dadeslam You've got a point there...almost, since I didn't assume $\;A,\,P\;$ commute , but rather that $\;AP+PA\;$  *is symmetric*, as you can easily check. And again this matrix is diagonalizable, and since the eigenvalues of $\;AP,\,PA\;$ are all negative, then its eigenvalues also are negative and it is thus ND. (check this, page 175: http://www.ams.org/notices/200102/200102FullIssue.pdf). Very interesting...and not a trivial problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't get it, ok $AP+PA$ is symmetric but the single $AP$ and $PA$ are not in general, so all the results in that PDF do not apply, as far as I understand, since they hold for symmetric matrices. Playing a little bit with matrices I've found a counter example which you can find added in the question..do you understand why this case does not work?